# How to optimize MySQL query with JOIN and WHERE?

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have two MySQL tables:

- shows (banner shows)
- clicks (banner clicks).

```
CREATE TABLE `shows` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`data` text NOT NULL,
`created_at` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `clicks` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`show_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`data` text NOT NULL,
`created_at` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
KEY `show_constaraint_idx` (`show_id`),
CONSTRAINT `show_constaraint` FOREIGN KEY (`show_id`) REFERENCES `shows` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Each table has 40 000 000 records.

I added 40 000 000 records to shows table:

```
drop procedure if exists doWhile;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE doWhile()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
WHILE (i <= 40000000) DO
INSERT INTO `shows` (data, created_at) values (
    CONCAT(MD5(RAND()), MD5(RAND())),
    FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp('2021-01-01') + floor(rand() * (unix_timestamp('2021-12-31') - unix_timestamp('2021-01-01') + 1)))
);
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END;
//
CALL doWhile();
```

I added 40 000 000 records to clicks table:

```
drop procedure if exists doWhile;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE doWhile()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
WHILE (i <= 40000000) DO
INSERT INTO `clicks` (show_id, data, created_at) values (
    (FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 40000000)),
    CONCAT(MD5(RAND()), MD5(RAND())),
    FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp('2021-01-01') + floor(rand() * (unix_timestamp('2021-12-31') - unix_timestamp('2021-01-01') + 1)))
);
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END;
//
CALL doWhile();
```

SQL query execution time is 10 sec:

```
SELECT shows.id,
    shows.data,
    clicks.id,
    clicks.data
FROM clicks
INNER JOIN shows ON shows.id = clicks.show_id
WHERE shows.created_at = '2021-03-03'
AND clicks.created_at >= '2021-03-03'
AND clicks.created_at <= '2021-03-06'
```

I tried to optimize SQL query, but SQL query execution time is 10 sec:

```
SELECT sub_shows.id,
    sub_shows.data,
    sub_clicks.id,
    sub_clicks.data
FROM (
    SELECT clicks.id,
        clicks.show_id,
        clicks.data
    FROM clicks
    WHERE clicks.created_at >= '2021-03-03' AND clicks.created_at <= '2021-03-06'
) as sub_clicks
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT shows.id,
        shows.data
    FROM shows
    WHERE shows.created_at = '2021-03-03'
) as sub_shows ON sub_shows.id = sub_clicks.show_id
```

EXPLAIN same for both queries:
[image]

How can I optimize the query?

**Answer:
Change innodb_buffer_pool_size to 12G
(Rick James)**

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` before your query and post the results on the question

Comment: look  in the mysql error log if there are any entries. you can also try a combined key for both tables instead of separate ones

Comment: What version of mysql is this, becuase in 8.0.27 this: `created_at date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()` throws: `ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created_at'`

Comment: @Luuk 'SELECT VERSION();' returned: '10.3.22-MariaDB'

Comment: I tried both your queries, using `10.5.12-MariaDB`, and they give a result within 0.1 sec.   Can you share anything about OS, internal memory, what kind of hard-disk?   Hmmzzz, I only have 1000000 records in `clicks`....

Comment: @Luuk OS Windows 10, RAM 16 Gb, SSD

Comment: `created_at` is `DATE`.  Perhaps you wanted `DATETIME`?  If so, the queries need changing.

Comment: How many rows are being returned?  If it is "millions", then 10 seconds is reasonable.

Comment: There is an extra level of subqueries; get rid of it; then we can talk further.

Comment: @RickJames I wanted DATE. Query returned 1321 rows. I run nnichols
  query table_size_MB: '12122.9063', buffer_pool_MB: '134217728.0000'

Comment: The buffer_pool is "tiny", but the table is even smaller.  If you expect the dataset to grow a lot, keep in mind to increase the buffer pool up to 70% of available RAM.

Comment: Wait... Is that 12GB of data and 128TB of buffer_pool?  Something is wrong!

Comment: @RickJames maybe should "SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/(1024*1024)" instead "SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/(1024/1024)"? buffer_pool_MB: '128'

Comment: Sorry about the typo in the query. Is that with increased buffer_pool and the compound indices? Ditch the sub-queries, they will be optimised out anyway.

Comment: Change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 12G, then check the timings again.

Comment: @RickJames thanks. I increased innodb_buffer_pool_size to 12G and my SQL queries (no optimized and optimized) execution time is 0.2 sec

Comment: Out of interest, did you test the performance difference with and without the compound indices?

Comment: @nnichols I tested with compound indices and innodb_buffer_pool_size 128M, execution time is 12 sec. I increased innodb_buffer_pool_size to 12G, execution time is 0.2 sec

Comment: I meant the difference between with and without the compound indices, with increased buffer pool. You can set the index as invisible so you don't have to drop and rebuild - `ALTER TABLE shows ALTER INDEX index_name INVISIBLE;`

Comment: @nnichols With increased buffer pool and with compound indices execution time is 0.2 sec. With increased buffer pool and without any indices execution time is 24 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better to have a compound index covering BOTH parts of the join criteria vs individual.

```
Suggest Indexes as listed
Shows    ( created_at, id )
Clicks   ( show_id, created_at )
```

The reason for both keys to help is that an index utilize both parts without having to go to the raw data pages to qualify the records.  Only after qualifying does it need to retrieve the additional columns in result set.

I would also adjust and reverse the query to the smallest granular item... The SHOWS table on the single date in the primary FROM position of the query.

```
SELECT 
      shows.id,
      shows.data,
      c.id,
      c.data
   FROM
      shows s
         JOIN clicks c
            ON s.id = c.show_id
          AND c.created_at >= '2021-03-03'
          AND c.created_at <= '2021-03-06'   
   WHERE 
      s.created_at = '2021-03-03'
```

Comment: I replaced my index to compound index.
shows: KEY `created_at_id` (`created_at`,`id`)
clicks: KEY `show_id_created_at` (`show_id`,`created_at`)

My query execution time is 12 sec. 

My optimized query execution time is 12 sec. 

Your query execution time is 12 sec.